# Contrapositive Fitch Proof

Tags: logic, fitch

I can't seem to figure out how to get past this step. Any suggestions?
[image]

Comment: I assume you are not permitted to use or do not have modus tollens. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_tollens

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to use modus tollens, then the result would follow quickly. Here is an example of that using a different proof checker:

[image]

However, if you have to derive this using introduction and elimination rules, the following might work using a proof provided by the authors of *forallx* (page 170):

[image]

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

P. D. Magnus, Tim Button with additions by J. Robert Loftis remixed and revised by Aaron Thomas-Bolduc, Richard Zach, forallx Calgary Remix: An Introduction to Formal Logic, Fall 2019. http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/forallxyyc.pdf

Comment: Thanks so much!! This was very helpful